# Project Management software

Tags: project-management

i'm interested in project management software similar to MS Project.  the project is a serious rebuild of my software.  we have a bug management system already but i need to track project progress.

i don't like web-based apps so much because the data is either hosted off-site or i need to set up my own server.

i like MS Project but it doesn't seem to compare estimated time with actual time and use it to pro-rate the future work estimates.

i'd like a gantt chart & calendar view.

thank you for your help!

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240/project-trackingmanagement-tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please give [open workbench](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openworkbench/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [rundown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software) from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

From the list that Ben Hoffstein provided, two caught my eye - [eGroupWare](http://www.egroupware.org/) and [Project Pier](http://www.projectpier.org/). Although those two might not meet your needs, they appear to be worth looking at for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I used primavera some time back, and I think it can do the said comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when Joel posted about the new Fogbugz [Evidence Based Scheduling](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/learnmore.html?section=PredictShipDates).  Seems like it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's web-based, but [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) tracks time, and can be combined with the [GreenHopper](http://www.greenpeppersoftware.com/en/products/GreenHopper/) plugin to give an Agile-style Planning Board and Burn-down chart. It doesn't, however, do velocity for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the open source tool [OpenProj](http://www.openproj.org/openproj), worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

since i'm a one-man project, it became clear the best solution for me was an [Excel workbook](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/plan.xls) that tracks time management & pro-rates remaining tasks.  the Recalculate macro updates the statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Try Crew! http://www.devmynd.com/crew